# Is there a word for someone who is not a parent?

Tags: single-word-requests

You can say of a person that they are single/married/divorced/widowed, even that that person is a parent (father or mother). But is there a single word to refer to someone who is not a parent?

I can only think of some compounds such as *childless* or *kidless*, but I'm not sure if they convey the meaning proposed. I have read somewhere that there is an acronym but I don't know if it's widely used: DINK, but it refers to couples without kids (Double Income No Kids), not to a single person.

Comment: Why, historically, would there be such a word? Children are associated with parents.  A childless person is what it says.

Comment: A person without descendants.

Answer (score -2):

**bachelor:**

A man who has never been married and most likely has no children.

**bachelorette:**

The female version of the above.

**spinster:**

A woman who has never been married and has no children (offensive).

Comment: These words only refer to not being married. They don't imply non-parenthood.

Comment: @puppetsock: "A bachelor with three kids." "The spinster who lived across the street had one daughter and two sons."

Comment: Both of those phrases are entirely possible. In addition, *spinster* is no more offensive than *homosexual*; though both are used derogatorily. the words themselves are purely descriptive

Comment: @TimLymington: One could use a qualifier to offset the offensive connotations. For instance: "an honest spinster."